# Carthage Build Failed after updating swift to version 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage

Carthage build failed after updating swift to version 4.0 from version 3.2.
Here are the results of using the `carthage update --platform iOS`.

```
*** Fetching AlamofireImage
*** Fetching FSCalendar
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Fetching ActiveLabel.swift
*** Fetching Toaster
*** Fetching PopupDialog
*** Fetching DKImagePickerController
*** Checking out DKImagePickerController at "3.6.1"
*** Checking out PopupDialog at "0.5.4"
*** Checking out Toaster at "2.1.0"
*** Checking out ActiveLabel.swift at "0.8.0"
*** Checking out Alamofire at "4.5.1"
*** Checking out FSCalendar at "2.7.9"
*** Checking out AlamofireImage at "3.3.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/6z/c0myz1fn4rsgy842p9vqqr700000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.my2Am1.log
*** Building scheme "ActiveLabel" in ActiveLabel.xcodeproj
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 65:
    /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/poqw/Documents/GitHub/nyg-ios/Carthage/Checkouts/ActiveLabel.swift/ActiveLabel.xcodeproj -scheme ActiveLabel -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/poqw/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.0_9A235/ActiveLabel.swift/0.8.0 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES build (launched in /Users/poqw/Documents/GitHub/nyg-ios/Carthage/Checkouts/ActiveLabel.swift)

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/6z/c0myz1fn4rsgy842p9vqqr700000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.my2Am1.log
```

And then `$ tail /var/folders/6z/c0myz1fn4rsgy842p9vqqr700000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.my2Am1.log`

I got this :

```
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:~/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/poqw/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/opt/local/bin"
    /usr/bin/ditto -rsrc /Users/poqw/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.0_9A235/ActiveLabel.swift/0.8.0/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ActiveLabel.build/Release-iphoneos/ActiveLabel.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ActiveLabel.swiftdoc /Users/poqw/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.0_9A235/ActiveLabel.swift/0.8.0/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/ActiveLabel.framework/Modules/ActiveLabel.swiftmodule/arm.swiftdoc

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/poqw/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.0_9A235/ActiveLabel.swift/0.8.0/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ActiveLabel.build/Release-iphoneos/ActiveLabel.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ActiveLabel_vers.o /Users/poqw/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.0_9A235/ActiveLabel.swift/0.8.0/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ActiveLabel.build/Release-iphoneos/ActiveLabel.build/DerivedSources/ActiveLabel_vers.c normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/poqw/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.0_9A235/ActiveLabel.swift/0.8.0/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ActiveLabel.build/Release-iphoneos/ActiveLabel.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ActiveLabel_vers.o /Users/poqw/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.0_9A235/ActiveLabel.swift/0.8.0/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ActiveLabel.build/Release-iphoneos/ActiveLabel.build/DerivedSources/ActiveLabel_vers.c normal arm64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
```

And Here is What I have done for fix this problem.

- Delete derived Carthage Cache.
- Delete Carthage directory in project.
- Uninstall Carthage and install again.
- Download Xcode 8.3.2 and `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode8.app/Contents/Developer` and use the `xcrun` command to make sure that the version has been changed to swift 3.0 and then update Carthage.
- Clean Project and rebuild
- Restart Xcode

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using Xcode 8.3.1 and this is what I followed:

```
Deleted derived data.
Removed Carthage folder: rm -r ./Carthage
Updated Cartfile with:
  github "facebook/facebook-sdk-swift" "master"
  github "facebook/facebook-ios-sdk" "sdk-version-4.21.0"
```

Run Carthage command:

```
carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to this question. But the solution you are suggesting is something I've already done. And it still does not seem to be resolved :(

Comment: I had many issues with this and oddly enough, I found that resetting my Mac made a huge difference.

Comment: Thx. But in the end I did not solve it in any way. So I formatted my macbook, and now it works well.

Comment: Welcome. I had the issue again and I found doing a Clean, and ulding for the simulator first helped.

Comment: Seems like deleting derived data is enough. At least for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mac Senour’s solution didn't work for me; what worked was cleaning derived data of CarthageKit here: `/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/`